# I am getting error when tried to connect TFS after restart

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I getting below error in VS 2017 I tried to connect TFS. After removal of server details it wont ask for credentials as well. Please help!!

TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server tfs.XXXX.com\XXX.
Technical information (for administrator):
  Unable to connect to the remote server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced same issue, It could be issue with fiddler, Please open the fiddler and it prompts certain popup, you just need to allow it.

Basically, fiddler block your request to TFS server.

It wont work even if i cleaned cache.
Solution: Keep open fiddler and allow requests if prompts.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually due to the corrupt TFS cache. But there can be few other reasons such as antivirus in your client machine. You can refer to the discussion thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109895/tf400324-team-foundation-services-are-not-available-from-server-server-collect) to get more details on different causes of this issue and how to get it fixed.