# Not able to connect to TFS and get a file from C#

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

This is the code I have used. Some days it worked properly but suddenly it stopped working.

```
        var TFS_UserName = "UserName";
        var TFS_Pass = "Password";
        var domain = "domain";
        var tfsUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSUri"];
        Uri uri = new Uri(tfsUri);

        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(TFS_UserName, TFS_Pass, domain);
        BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(cred);
        TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
        tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(uri, tfsCred);
        try
        {
            tpc.Authenticate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "User not Authorized" + ex.Message;
        }
        var vcServer = (VersionControlServer)tpc.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
        var LocalPath = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSave"]);
        var tempAddress = "File Path";
        var i = vcServer.GetItem(@"$/Folder/Path/" + tempAddress + "/" + "FileName");
        i.DownloadFile(LocalPath + "FileName");
```

This code is suddenly started throwing exception at ***tpc.Authenticate();***

The Exception is:
TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://tfs/Address.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Ex Source : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client

Inner Ex: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
{Inner Ex: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.}

Comment: Could it be just a network issue?

Comment: I am able to login to that TFS link in browser and Visual studio as well. In Server also this code was working we have used that for more than a month. After that suddenly started giving exception.

Comment: I took the code from this link while developing https://gist.github.com/software-mariodiana/e2ab5eb9a9ed4ed441f2

Comment: Just refer to this thread for troubleshoot : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109895/tf400324-team-foundation-services-are-not-available-from-server-server-collect, Clean all the caches if you installed multiple version of clients, check Certificate ... hope that helps.

Comment: Did you use proxy when connect to TFS server?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Basic Authentication doing the problem, try to connect with this way:

```
var TFS_UserName = "UserName";
var TFS_Pass = "Password";
var domain = "domain";
var tfsUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSUri"];
Uri uri = new Uri(tfsUri);

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, cred);
try
{
    tfsCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return "User not Authorized" + ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: With this change also getting the same Exception TF400324

Comment: Ok, please read this article: http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/03/solved-tf400324-team-foundation-services-are-not-available-from-server/

Comment: Read the blog but its telling that solution is valid only when I am doing a Hobby project. But its a team Project.. So that is not useful for my case.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to make sure you can access to TFS in web portal on the machine that runs the code.

Then, try to clean the Cache folder on the computer that runs the code. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.

Also, try to remove the windows credentials that related to TFS in `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`.

Comment: I am able to login to that TFS link in browser and Visual studio as well. In Server also this code was working we have used that for more than a month. After that suddenly started giving exception.  The solution you provided didn't work for me. I tried this..

Comment: Did you login to TFS in browser and Visual studio on the same machine as the code ran?

Comment: Yes.. the code was running in Local Machine also. I tried both the ways.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I am using 7.0 in Local

Comment: Try to also clean the cache folder on the server, the path is similar as `C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache` (You can get the cache folder path from Administration Console). After cleaned, on Server machine, click Start and select Run… to open the dialog box, then input `iisreset.exe` and click OK, wait it run completely.

Comment: First I need to make this work in Local machine.. Actually I don't have access to the server. I can develop the thing and push the code to server by means of automatic Build to server.

Comment: This error means your code can't connect to the server, how about run this code on another machine? It seems you have set up https with SSL for your server, you may also try to use http on your server to see whether it works.