# VS 2017 Team Explorer - No Repositories Available

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I have a new Team Foundation Server that we are hosting - Version 16.131.28226.3. It is over an SSL connection and has a valid certificate.

I have created a new Team Project named "Test".

The project source control type is Git.

In Visual Studio 2017 - 15.9.4 Team Explorer, I can clone this git repo under Local Git Repositories. And I have successfully added and pushed to the server.

However, if I try to connect to this new Team Foundation Server - Manage Connections, Connect To a Project, Add TFS Server; when I add the TFS server, there is an exclamation icon next to and if I hover on the server name it says

> No Repositories Available

when selected, the Connect button is disabled. In the screenshot below, the second highlighted server is the one in question:

[image]

So the Local Repo is not associated with the Team Repo, thus I can't assign Work Items to my checkins, etc..

I have explicitly added myself as a User to the Project, I don't know what else to do.  Any advice?

Comment: Did you connect to a project? Maybe you should explore the doc more. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/work-team-explorer?view=vsts It should not be a problem there.

Comment: Connect button is disabled

Comment: Can you see your collection/project in web or admin console?

Comment: @wannadream - yes, it is fully available from the tfs website. I can see my checkin history, etc.

Comment: Are you able to connect to it with git cli?

Comment: @wannadream, yes, i can clone, push, pull, etc.

Comment: Have your tried it with VS 2015? This looks like the same problem you have: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/232139/there-are-no-repositories-available.html

Comment: I haven't tried 2015, i'm going to try 2019. I did try deleting the 2 folders per your link with no success

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My issue was - on the server, Team Foundation Server Administrative Console, the Public URL was incorrect. Our public URL had changed to a full domain name with https and the public url was still set to the old http LAN address.

---

**Bounty Edit:**

This actually worked! I checked TfsMgmt.exe and had specified only https://MachineName for the Public URL.

[image]

I edited it and specified the Fully Qualified Domain Name, ignored an error when clicking the test link, then I restarted the TFS Server(s) including the SQL.

Ps I previously had to add the certificate, add a trusted URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43036526/495455 and I also added the TFS Server into Windows Credentials Manager with my username/password.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a few days back when I am into a new project we use VSTS. The admin need to provide the permissions to you access the repo. If permission is given we need to make sure we are on the right URL and the branch you are permitted.

---

finally, Crosscheck

- You have permission to the repo
- You are on the correct branch
- URL is correct
- If nothing works Go and inform your admin