# Team city Proxy Change not taking to effect and failing to connect to Version Control

Tags: azure, azure-devops, teamcity, devops

I am a developer and we recently updated the proxy setting in our organization, so I went in and updated the proxy setting in the Internal.Properties file. I restarted the whole team city server. but still I am having issues with Team city connecting to the Azure Devops url, ie. https://dev.azure.com/. I am not sure what else to do, can somebody please help me with this, i really appreciate it.

[image: Proxy setting not taking to effect]

Comment: There is not any Azure Version Control, are you talking about  Azure DevOps Service url like https://dev.azure.com/xxx or https://xxx.visualstudio.com  and Azure DevOps Server url like https// tfssevername:8080/tfs?

Comment: Hi PatrickLu, Yes, I am talking about Dev.Azure.com/XXX, will update my question...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you able to directly access the Azure DevOps which  not through Team City Server such as browser? This will narrow down if the issue is related to the proxy configuration of Team City or your network environment.

Comment: Hi PatrickLu, Yes I am able to access the dev.azure.com from the browser. But for some reason when I run the build, I get an error... seems like its still looking at the old proxy. I updated the registry, environment variable, gitconfigs under user accounts.not sure where it is reading the old proxy.    Failed to start build #3 at 03 Apr 20 10:21 on ENTLLC0919-Build3: Failed to perform checkout on agent: Failed to list workspaces: TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server https://dev.azure.com/DevTechABC/.

Comment: Hi User5144,  According to  your description, since you are able to access the dev.azure.com from the browser. Not sure if it's just related to the configuration/settings of proxy in teamcity side. It that is the root cause, afraid you may have to ask help from teamcity related community.  For the error TF400324 you are getting, kindly take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109895/tf400324-team-foundation-services-are-not-available-from-server-server-collect/48618076 Check if there is a solution helpful for you.